# Как .net взаимодействует с железом и устройствами ПК?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Как взаимодействует .net (в том числе WPF, UWP) с железом и устройствами ПК. Например, с монитором или файловой системой.

Мне известно, что C# не имеет прямого доступа к железу. Он преобразуется в промежуточный код IL затем общеязыковая исполняющая среда CLR выполняет программу.

Например, DirectoryInfo из пространства System.IO содержит методы для управления каталогами. Данный класс написан полностью на C# и, как я понимаю, С# не может знать, что позади CLR есть жёсткий диск или монитор. Но CLR как-то узнает о том, что данный класс хочет получить информацию о каталоге, а другой класс хочет вывести сообщение на экран.

Возможно вопрос не поставлен правильно. Я всего лишь увлекаюсь программированием.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду .net возможно? c# это язык программирования, он ни с чем не взаимодействует.

Comment: Да, точно. Имел в виду .net. Исправлю вопрос.

Comment: clr "узнает" об этом в зависимости от того что вы вызываете, если это `DirectoryInfo` то она "понимает" что надо дёрнуть системный вызов ОС которая предоставить данные файловой системы

Comment: Никакая программа никак не взаимодействует ни с железом, ни с файловой системой. Всё делается через системные вызовы к ОС, а в сишарп прокинуты соответствующие биндинги к нужным системным API. Класс FileStream взаимодействует с Win32 API, а модуль Win32Native уже содержит биндинги к нативному kernel32.dll, и где-то там уже системные вызовы.

Comment: Если вам интересно, как это устроено, можете посмотреть на исходный код того же [DirectoryInfo](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directoryinfo.cs,30fa608717e5ce8e), @andreymal уже кратко описал, как это работает.